# Why are these sums equal to each other?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I have the sum $$\sum_{m\leq n}\sum_{\substack{abc=m\\a\leq A\\b\leq B}} f(a,b) \,g(m)$$
which I believe should equal
$$\sum_{r\leq AB}\sum_{s\leq n/r}\sum_{\substack{tu=r\\t\leq A\\r\leq B}}f(t,u)\,g(rs). \tag{1}$$

Previously, I had the simpler sum $\sum_{m\leq n}\sum_{\substack{ab=m\\a\leq A}} f(a,b)\,g(m)$, which I wanted to show was equal to $\sum_{r\leq A}\sum_{s\leq n/r}f(r,s)\,g(rs)$. I did this using a characteristic function:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{m\leq n}\sum_{\substack{ab=m\\a\leq A}} f(a,b)\,g(m)&=\sum_{m\leq n}\sum_{a\leq A} \mathbf 1_{ab=m}f(a,b)\,g(m)\\
&=\sum_{a\leq A}\sum_{m\leq n} \mathbf 1_{ab=m}f(a,b)\,g(ab)\\
&=\sum_{a\leq A}\sum_{b\leq n/a} f(a,b)\,g(ab).
\end{align*}

I've been trying to produce a similar derivation for $(1)$, but I can't seem to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to introduce a variable $r=ab$, adding a superficial sum:
\begin{align*}
 \sum_{m\leq n}\sum_{\substack{abc=m\\a\leq A\\b\leq B}} f(a,b) \,g(m)&=\sum_{m\leq n}\sum_{a\leq A}\sum_{b\leq B} \mathbf 1_{abc=m}f(a,b)g(m)\\[-40pt]
&=\sum_{r\leq AB}\sum_{m\leq n}\sum_{a\leq A}\sum_{b\leq B} \mathbf 1_{r=ab}\mathbf 1_{abc=m}f(a,b)g(m)\\[4pt]
&=\sum_{r\leq AB}\sum_{c\leq n/r}\sum_{a\leq A}\sum_{b\leq B} \mathbf 1_{r=ab}\mathbf 1_{abc=m}f(a,b)g(rc)\\
&=\sum_{r\leq AB}\sum_{c\leq n/r}\sum_{\substack{ab=r\\a\leq A\\b\leq B}} \mathbf 1_{r=ab}\mathbf 1_{abc=m}f(a,b)g(rc)\\
&=\sum_{r\leq AB}\sum_{c\leq n/r}\sum_{\substack{ab=r\\a\leq A\\b\leq B}} f(a,b)g(rc)
\end{align*}
since now the characteristic functions are always $1$.